# Zen sub-theme CSS class confusion <div class="region region-sidebar-first column sidebar">

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-theming

I created a Zen sub-theme called mytheme and copied the contents of `/sites/all/themes/zen/STARTERKIT/css` to `/sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/`, and assigned the **Navigation** block to the **First sidebar** region.

I want to know which CSS file controls the styling of the Navigation menu, so I loaded the site in my web browser (Google Chrome 7.0.517.44).

The Navigation block is contained in a div with `class="region region-sidebar-first column sidebar"`. I highlighted this code using Firebug, which tells me that the class is defined in: `http://www.mysite.dev/sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/layout-fixed.css`.

There isn't a CSS class called `region region-sidebar-first column sidebar` in layout-fixed.css, but there is a class called `.region-sidebar-first`, which I assume are relates to 'region region-sidebar-first column sidebar'.

[What characters are valid in CSS class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names/449000#449000) SO topic says "name must start with an underscore (_), a dash (-), or a letter(a–z), followed immediately 1 by a letter or underscore, and then any number of dashes, underscores, letters, or numbers", which makes sense.

But how does `.region-sidebar-first` end up as `'class="region region-sidebar-first column sidebar"'` in the HTML source code? This is confusing for beginners like myself, and if anyone can explain the logic behind this naming convention, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are multiple classes applied to the same element. You separate multiple classes with a space. So, technically, there are four classes applied there.

Comment: The four classes being:

1. region
2. region-sidebar-first
3. column
4. sidebar

Comment: Thanks Brandon. How do I find out where the .region, .column and .siderbar classes are defined? None of these classes appear in 'Matched CSS Rules' in Firebug.

Comment: It's quite possible some are no longer used, and it's also quite possible they're used only for targeting that element with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can give an element several classes, seperated with spaces. Your element has four classes in total: region, region-sidebar-first, column and sidebar.